# Create service POST spring framework

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, post

I have a service in spring phase, where I get an object like @ResquestBody to perform the registration, the POST method however is not working, returning an error when the JSON step. Below is the error and codes:

Error:
[Image (Unexpected '<')](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FBew.png)

Code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/cliente/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<?> createUser(@RequestBody Cliente user) {
    logger.info("Creating User : {}", user);

    if (clienteService.isUserExist(user)) {
        logger.error("Unable to create. A User with name {} already exist", user.getNome());
        return new ResponseEntity(new CustomErrorType("Unable to create. A User with name " +
        user.getNome() + " already exist."),HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
    }
    clienteService.save(user);
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Class:

```
   @Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
public class Cliente implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String nome;
    private String telefone;
    private String endereco;
    private String cidade;
    private String estado;
    private String cnpjCpf;
    private String email;
    private String senha;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "imagem")
    private byte[] imagem;

    public Cliente(Long id, String nome, String telefone, String endereco, String cidade, String estado,
            String cnpjCpf, String email, String senha, byte[] imagem) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.telefone = telefone;
        this.endereco = endereco;
        this.cidade = cidade;
        this.estado = estado;
        this.cnpjCpf = cnpjCpf;
        this.email = email;
        this.senha = senha;
        this.imagem = imagem;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getTelefone() {
        return telefone;
    }

    public void setTelefone(String telefone) {
        this.telefone = telefone;
    }

    public String getEndereco() {
        return endereco;
    }

    public void setEndereco(String endereco) {
        this.endereco = endereco;
    }

    public String getCidade() {
        return cidade;
    }

    public void setCidade(String cidade) {
        this.cidade = cidade;
    }

    public String getEstado() {
        return estado;
    }

    public void setEstado(String estado) {
        this.estado = estado;
    }

    public String getCnpjCpf() {
        return cnpjCpf;
    }

    public void setCnpjCpf(String cnpjCpf) {
        this.cnpjCpf = cnpjCpf;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }

    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }

    public byte[] getImagem() {
        return imagem;
    }

    public void setImagem(byte[] imagem) {
        this.imagem = imagem;
    }

    public static long getSerialversionuid() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + (int) (id ^ (id >>> 32));
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Cliente other = (Cliente) obj;
        if (id != other.id)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

See in the image that when performing POST with postman application we can get the error.

Security:

```
   @Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityWebConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private ImplementsUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/fornecedor/lista").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/fornecedor/cadastrarFornecedor").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .and()
            .rememberMe()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .rememberMe()
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService).and().csrf()
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied");

        http
        .sessionManagement()
            .sessionFixation().migrateSession()
            .invalidSessionUrl("/login")
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS)
            .maximumSessions(1)
            .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
            .expiredUrl("/login")
            .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
        .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/css/**", "/data-table/**", "/Doc/**", "/font-awesome/**", "/img/**", "/javascripts/**", "/js/**", "/stylesheets/**");
    }

    @Bean
    SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
        return new SessionRegistryImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
    }
}
```

Return:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/dialect">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>CompraFacil</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS-->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
    href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Google fonts - Roboto -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,700">
    <!-- theme stylesheet-->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.blue.css"
    id="theme-stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom stylesheet - for your changes-->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/custom.css">
    <!-- Favicon-->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico">
    <!-- you can replace it by local Font Awesome-->
    <script type="application/javascript"
    src="https://use.fontawesome.com/99347ac47f.js"></script>
    <!-- Font Icons CSS-->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://file.myfontastic.com/da58YPMQ7U5HY8Rb6UxkNf/icons.css">
    <script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/login" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="c78362dd-e239-4b46-959b-0c3df8347abc"/>
        <div class="page login-page">
            <div class="container d-flex align-items-center">
                <div class="form-holder has-shadow">
                    <div class="row">
                        <!-- Logo & Information Panel-->
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="info d-flex align-items-center">
                                <div class="content">
                                    <div class="logo">
                                        <h1>CompraFacil</h1>
                                    </div>
                                    <p>Uma plataforma de ecommerce B2C.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Form Panel    -->
                        <div class="col-lg-6 bg-white">
                            <div class="form d-flex align-items-center">
                                <div class="content">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" name="username" class="input-material">
                                        <label for="login-username" placeholder="exemplo@dominio.com"
                                            class="label-material">E-mail</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="password" name="password" class="input-material">
                                        <label for="login-password" class="label-material">Senha</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"
                                        value="Acessar">
                                    <br>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="remember-me" name="remember-me" />
                                        <label for="remember-me">Lembrar?</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- This should be submit button but I replaced it with <a> for demo purposes-->
                                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"
                                        data-placement="right" class="forgot-pass">Esqueceu a
                                        senha?</a>
                                    <br>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="copyrights text-center">
                <p>
                    Design by 
                    <a href="https://bootstrapious.com/admin-templates"
                        class="external">Bootstrapious</a>
                </p>
                <!-- Please do not remove the backlink to us unless you support further theme's development at https://bootstrapious.com/donate. It is part of the license conditions. Thank you for understanding :)-->

            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf"
            value="c78362dd-e239-4b46-959b-0c3df8347abc" />
    </form>
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                        aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Informe seu endereço
                        de e-mail</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form action="@{Logins.esqueciSenha}" method="POST">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Digite seu e-mail:</label>
                                    <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                                        <input type="email" name="email" value="${flash['email']}"
                                            class="form-control" title="Informe o seu endereço de email."
                                            aria-describedby="sizing-addon7" required>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Somehow my security may be blocking my post, I could not identify, I'm new with spring.

Comment: Explain what exactly you get in the postman. On your screenshot there is JSON response. So what exactly is your problem?

Comment: @mentallurg the problem is that I am not able to save the object I am sending in JSON format, and I do not know why it is giving this error

Comment: Where the problem occurs - on the client or on the server? If on the client, e.g. in the postman, show error text. If on server, set breakpoint and tell us what problem in which line happens.

Comment: @mentallurg I think somehow security is blocking, I'll post the code.

Comment: what about adding `consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE , produces =  MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE' in the `RequestMapping anotation` ?

Comment: @wdc same problem